# how to detect that app is opening from safari redirect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, deeplink

I want to detect safari redirection to my app.
When I enter URI (deeplink) `AppName://parameter/id` in safari, it opens my app with home page screen, but I want to redirect to specific screen based on `id` in link.

When I send this same deeplink url from push notification, it calls `didReceiveRemoteNotification` and I'm redirecting there.

Is there any method which calls after redirecting from safari?

How can I detect that my app is launched (or open in foreground) from safari?

I'm in objective c project. XCode 9.

Comment: Have you tried the examples in “Handling URL Requests” from the “Inter-App Communication” section in the “iOS App Programming Guide”? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can know which application ask yours to open. The only think you can know is which URL was used. Now you can catch the url from your application delegate. See [application:openURL:options:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?language=objc)

Answer (score 1):

Need use "Implementing a Custom URL Scheme"
see here:
http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Answer (score 0):

I had deprecated method in my code for open Url, which was not being called.

I replaced it with new method `application:openURL:options:` and it worked.